# Intercepting MQTT messages in ActiveMQ Artemis

Tags: activemq-artemis

Can someone please guide me on how to intercept MQTT messages on ActiveMQ Artemis broker? I tried as suggested in the manual but the MQTT messages are not intercepting. However the publishing and subscribing of messages are working fine.

Interceptor class:

```
public class InterceptorExample implements Interceptor {
      @Override
      public boolean intercept(Packet packet, RemotingConnection connection) throws ActiveMQException {
           System.out.println("Packet intercepted");
           return true;
      }
}
```

I add the interceptor to the configuration in addMQTTConnector method

```
protected void addMQTTConnector() throws Exception {        

    .
    .
    .
    List<String> incomingInterceptors = new ArrayList<>();
    incomingInterceptors.add("org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.protocol.mqtt.InterceptorExample");
    server.getConfiguration().setIncomingInterceptorClassNames(incomingInterceptors);

}
```

full code for the broker class is at https://codeshare.io/snZsB

Answer (score 0):

I [filled a feature request](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ARTEMIS-607) for Interceptor support in MQTT. It is already implemented and was released in Artemis 1.4.0.

In Artemis 1.3.0, only messages sent over the core protocol (and maybe one more other than MQTT) could be intercepted.